# GeoJSON file containing tons of point features

Tags: file, geojson, shapefile

I need a `GeoJSON` file containing tons (500 000+) of point features, (world cities, for example). I tried to find such file using Google, but I have not found. Can anybody provide me with such file or give a link to `.shp` file (I will convert to `GeoJson`)?

Answer (score 0):

Bob,

If you are looking for global coverage of features (i.e., world cities) I would recommend the [natural earth dataset](http://www.naturalearthdata.com). It provides excellent vector and raster data in a shapefile format. You mention the ability to convert from shapefile to geojson, but in case any others have questions on how to perform this operation, you can use Quantum GIS to export to geojson.